# Searching in eclipse using Regular expression

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to search for occurrences of something in my workspace which consist s of a string, a newline character and a string again
For example :

```
INSERT(  a newline here 
   Trev
```

P.S. : `Trev` is in the next line

I tried using File search in eclipse with Search with Regular expression ticked on

I tried `INSERT( \r \n Trev`

But seems this isn't coz working as I'm not getting any result. Hope I'm clear with my question. Could anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

You want this regex:

```
INSERT\(\s+\n\s+Trev
```

Note that you should escape the `(` character as it has a special meaning in regexes.